# Javascript stopped working in IE when debugging

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010

All of a sudden javascript stopped working in IE when I'm debugging in visual studio.  I verified that disable script debugging is unchecked and all the javascript works correctly in Chrome.

[image]

I noticed that when I run the application the .js files stopped getting loaded in the scripts document like they normally do but I'm not sure if that's the problem or not.

[image]

Comment: Did you accidentally enter a break-point somewhere? Not sure how to fix it .. reboot your computer? :P

Comment: I did reboot my computer. :|  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to let everyone know what I discovered.  If you're using the IE developer tools there is an additional way to turn off scripting.  I'm not sure if there is a shortcut I'm not aware of that enabled it or I accidentally clicked it but if you find yourself in the same solution then open the developer tools click disable and then scripting and that might be your problem.[image]